# Golang SMTP sending empty email

Tags: go, smtp

Why when I try to send email i'm received empty email?

```
    func contactHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        if r.Method == "GET" {
            t, _ := template.ParseFiles("template/static/contact.html")
            t.Execute(w, nil)
        } else if r.Method == "POST" {
            r.ParseForm()
            msg := "Name: " + r.Form["name"][0] + ", Email: " + r.Form["email"][0] + ", Message: " + r.Form["message"][0]
            println("out ", msg)
            smtp.SendMail("smtp.gmail.com:587", smtp.PlainAuth("", "login", "password", "smtp.gmail.com"), "sender@mail.com", []string{"me@mail.com"}, []byte(msg))
            http.Redirect(w, r, "/", 301)
        }
    }
```

But if I change `[]byte(msg)` to `[]byte("TEST")` I received email with TEST word

Comment: So what is the value of `msg`? Did you check it?

Comment: out  Name: NAME, Email: test@mail.com, Message: test test test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't make up the email header format as you please. The email header must follow a specific format defined in RFC2822. Try to build your variable 'msg' by using this format:

```
from := fmt.Sprintf("From: <%s>\r\n", "sender@gmail.com")
to := fmt.Sprintf("To: <%s>\r\n", "recipient@gmail.com")
subject := "Subject: This is the subject\r\n"
body := "This is the email body.\r\nBye\r\n"

msg := from+to+subject+"\r\n"+body
```

See details in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822